# div background-image not showing

Tags: html, css

I know this question has been asked here a lot, but nothing I've read has worked.

I'm using this in the CSS:

```
div.main {
    background-image: url("[DIRECTORY HERE]");
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 150px;
    left: 485px;
    height: 530px;
    width: 775px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Then I'm calling this in HTML like this:

```
<div class = 'main'>
        <!-- <img src = '[DIRECTORY HERE]'> -->
            <p id = 'content'></p>
        </div>
```

I was just using the img tag as you see, but I found that to be an inefficient/ineffective way of handling it.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I've tried every answer I've read here, and nothing has worked.

Comment: Can you can see the contents of your <p> tag if you populate it? Do you need the "z-index: -1;" setter?

Comment: Please complete your question for it to include somewhat of an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve): Is the resource file in the correct directory? Do the developer tools (element inspector) show the expected URL? Have you checked in the developer tools / debugger whether the resource file is actually found (e.g. 200 response)? Is the HTML element containing the background image or the image element itself large enough (check via element inspector) / isn’t obscured by some other element / isn’t otherwise hidden? Is the image normally viewable in the browser or is it corrupted?

Comment: @Eraph Yes, I populate it via a jQuery statement, and it doesn't cause the background-image to work. I've also populated it independently with no success.

Comment: @Xufox Hmm... odd. I went into the Inspector, and clicked the div element. In the CSS of this element it excludes the background-image, height, and width are removed. Why would this be?

Comment: If you set it to a plain colour, can you see the DIV? e.g. background-color: #00ff00;

Comment: @Eraph The div doesn't show with background-color, either.

Comment: Sounds like something else is hiding the div. Try removing either the position or the z-index (or both) setters and see if it shows up at all, might give you an idea of what's going on.

Comment: @VirtuallyRealistic that weird, i test your code with color and image (upload by a host) and both work fine. Can you post a image while you inspect the div?

Comment: @HenryVarro Here's an image: http://i.imgur.com/2RLR9vR.png

Comment: So... I'm an idiot. The reason it wasn't working is because I was using a media query from my previous monitor (It's resolution was 1900x900 instead of 1920x1080). So, any change I made didn't take effect because my monitor didn't fit the media query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image is the issue. The link doesn't work because it is pointing to an image on your computer. You need to either upload the image online and use an http:// or point to the folder by removing the http://. If you are editing the css online (and not simply on your computer), then you will need to make sure the image is accessible.

So basically choose either of these:
upload online to its own url:
background-image: url("[DIRECTORY HERE]");

using folder:
background-image: url("[DIRECTORY HERE]");

Everything is fine otherwise. Good luck.

Comment: Ps: Here is an example of a working image using the css methodology of adding a background-image from an image hosted online: .main {
    background-image: url("http://purrfectcatnames.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Gray-Cat-MorgueFile-Nov16th-2013.jpg");}

Answer (score 0):

You can use either: 
**Option 1**
**CSS:**

```
.main {
    background-image: url("[DIRECTORY HERE]");
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 150px;
    left: 485px;
    height: 530px;
    width: 775px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class = 'main'>
        <!--<img src = '[DIRECTORY HERE]'>--> 
        <p id = 'content'></p>
</div>
```

---

Or **Option 2:**

---

**CSS:**

```
div {
        background-image: url("[DIRECTORY HERE]");
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
        top: 150px;
        left: 485px;
        height: 530px;
        width: 775px;
        z-index: -1;
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <!-- <img src = '[DIRECTORY HERE]'> -->
    <p id = 'content'></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -5):

I think this should work.

CSS:

```
.main { background-image: url("insert image url");
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
top: 150px;
left: 485px;
height: 530px;
width: 775px;
z-index: -1;
}
```

I just removed "div" from "div.main"

Comment: Why would this make any difference?